# dplyr programatic way to filter most recent week

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

What is the best way to efficently filter the last/most recent week (on the basis it may not be a full week worth of data).

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(dates =
c("2014-12-17","2014-12-18","2014-12-21","2014-12-25","2014-12-26",
  "2015-05-17","2015-05-18","2015-05-21","2015-05-25","2015-05-26",
  "2016-06-17","2016-06-18","2016-06-21","2016-06-25","2016-06-26"))


df <- df %>% mutate(dates = ymd(dates),
                    the.year = year(dates),
                    the.week = week(dates))

#Filter the last week (as may not be complete)
```

I can come up with solution like this

```
max.week <- df %>% filter(the.year == max(the.year)) %>%
  filter(the.week == max(the.week)) %>%
  group_by(the.year, the.week) %>%
  summarise(count= n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(max.week = paste(the.year, the.week,sep="-")) %>% 
  select(max.week) %>%
  unlist(use.names = F)

df %>% filter(!paste(the.year, the.week, sep = "-") == max.week) 
   %>%
```

but there must be simplier solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`group_indices` can also help:

```
df %>% 
  filter(group_indices(., the.year, the.week) < max(group_indices(., the.year, the.week)))
```

Which can also be written as:

```
df %>% filter({id <- group_indices(., the.year, the.week)} < max(id))
```

or

```
df %>% 
  mutate(id = group_indices(., the.year, the.week)) %>% 
  filter(id < max(id))
```

Comment: Nice grouping. Was not aware of that function

Comment: Nice answer. Thanks. Fastest microbenchmark results with 100,000 rows .

Comment: @Axeman I have errors with `R 3.3.1` and `dplyr 0.5.0`. 1st and 3rd solution give `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : cannot handle` and 2nd sol gives `Error in filter_impl(.data, dots) : assignments are forbidden`. So I cannot check, but it seems that your solution only works when data (or factors) is sorted doesn't it ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper, you might need `dplyr v0.7.0` or higher, not sure. If data is unsorted, use `arrange(the.year, the.week)` first.

Comment: Thanks @Axeman. iboboru, did you include my solution for sorted data in your benchmark ?

Answer (score 4):

The shortest dplyr-way I can think of would be

```
filter(df, !{yw <- interaction(the.year, the.week)} %in% yw[which.max(dates)])
```

But you may want to break it down for better legibility:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(yearweek = paste(the.year, the.week, sep = "-")) %>% 
  filter(!yearweek %in% yearweek[which.max(dates)])
```

Remove the `!` to achieve the opposite effect.

Comment: You could remove the outer `{ }` in your first line.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
df %>% transform(yw= the.year *100 + the.week) %>% filter(yw != max(yw)) %>% select(-yw)
```

Or, if your data is sorted by date as seems to be the case :

```
df %>% filter(the.year !=last(the.year) | the.week !=last(the.week))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility using `dplyr`,

```
df %>% 
arrange(dates) %>% 
filter(the.week != last(the.week) | the.year != last(the.year))
```